# Showing all the images with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using numpy and matplotlib to read all the images in the folder for image processing techniques. Although, I have done the part of reading image dataset from folders and process it with numpy array. But the problem, I'm facing is of showing all the images with matplotlib.imshow function. Everytime I want to show all the images with imshow function, unfortunately it just give me first image nothing else. 
My code is below:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpplot
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

images = []
path = "../path/to/folder"
for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
    current_directory_path = os.path.abspath(root)
    for f in files:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
if ext == ".jpg":
   current_image_path = os.path.join(current_directory_path,f)
   current_image = mpimg.imread(current_image_path)
   images.append(current_image) 

for img in images:
    print len(img.shape)

i = 0

for i in range(len(img.shape)):
    mpplot.imshow(img)
    mpplot.show()
```

I will be thankful if somebody can help me in this.

P.S. I'm pretty new with python, numpy and also at stackoverflow. So, please don't mind if the question is unclear or not direct.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About showing only one plot in one moment: please get familiar with [matplotlib subplots](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot.html).

Also, what is your problem that you are not iterating over images. You are calling `img` x-times.

Try to iterate over images as below:

```
for img in images:
    mpplot.imshow(img)
    mpplot.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to add is `mpplot.figure()` before each `mpplot.show()`, this will open a new window for each image.